# Problema al renderizar pdfs en rails 4 en modo desarrollo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

use la libreria **wicked_pdf** el problema esta en la llamada a los estilos, soy nuevo en rails adjunto una imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi layout

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true  -%>
<%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<style>
  body {font-size: 9px !important;}
  h3 {font-size: 10px !important; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px; text-align: center;}
  table, tr, td, th, tbody, thead, tfoot {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
  }
  h2 {font-size: 13px !important;}
  p {font-size: 9px !important; text-align: justify;}
  .float-right {float: right; font-weight: bold;}
  p span {font-weight: bold;}
  .contract-signer{
    margin-top: 70px;
  }
  .contract-signer p{
    text-align: center;
  }
  #brake{
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
  table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 4px !important;
  }
  div.alwaysbreak { page-break-before: always; }
  div.nobreak:before { clear:both; }
  div.nobreak { page-break-inside: avoid; }
</style>
<script>
  function number_pages() {
    var vars={};
    var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
    for(var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = decodeURIComponent(z[1]);}
    var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
    for(var i in x) {
      var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
      for(var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
    }
  }
</script>
```

Contrato
    
    <%= yield %>

pero cuando yo corro en modo produccion me va bien alguna ayuda ?

Comment: El error tiene que ver con `wicked_pdf` ...debes ver que esta ocurriendo... El error señala que hay algo que les estas haciendo `start_width?` y eso es nil... Debes revisar a fondo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un guión al final de la línea. En vez de:

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true  -%>
```

es:

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

P.S. : por favor para la próxima pregunta, copia / pega el error en vez de sacar un pantallazo.  Es algo mucho más fácil de manejar, aparte que se puede leer fácilmente sin necesidad de una lupa. Saludos

**Actualizacion:**

Revisando [los issues de la gema](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/470), al parecer hay algun problema en como interpreta wicked_pdf las url de los assets a los que se accede a traves del comando `url()` de css. A algunos se les ha producido el error por bootstrap, a otros por font awesome, otros en sus propios css personalizados donde han usado `url`. Lo que te recomiendo para que puedas depurar el error:

- Comentas que no te da problemas en produccion, eso puede deberse a que ahi ya se encuentran compilados los assets y pueden ser accedidos. Podrias probar a hacer una compilacion local de tus assets con `rake assets:precompile` y ver si te sigue saliendo el error.
- Revisa tu `application.css` y anda comentando cada uno de tus `require` (o `@import` en caso que estes usando sass) para ver cual css es el que te esta dando problemas. Cuando lo logres identificar, busca alguna llamada a `url` y evalua si se esta usando en tu pdf generado para borrarla del css.
- En caso que no puedas borrar las llamadas a `url` de los css, porque afectaria los estilos del sitio web en general, considera el crear un archivo css distinto al `application.css`, algo como `<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'pdf' %>` donde se carguen unicamente los estilos a usar dentro de la generacion del pdf.

Comment: si perfecto muchas por el consejo, pero no es ese el error sigue saliendo lo mismo [ NoMethodError at /es/collections/daily.pdf
undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass  y puse tal y cual <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

Comment: +1 por el consejo de no pegar un pantallazo

Comment: @DarlyncinhoBravo revisa mi actualizacion. En caso de que no te ayude a encontrar una solucion, agrega el codigo de tu `application.css` para ver con mas detalle que linea puede estar causando el problema.